# Take input from console in format

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, multidimensional-array

I am wondering how I can take in input from the console in a specific format.

I'm looking to ask the user for an input in the format of

- `#,#` or
- `##`

and translate that into

- `#,#` or
- split the two numbers in some fashion

So that I can use those two numbers to find an object in a 2D array.

Essentially what I'm trying to do...

```
Ask user for input
Scanner take in values in form #,# or ##
Then be able to use/plug in values into 2D array 
So array[#][#] in some sort
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance !

Comment: Please start the code yourself and then ask for help.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code... this site is for asking question related to problems, not for writing others full code for you

Comment: The second format `##` can't be parsed, because there is no visible separator. Example `12,34` and `1234`. The second example could result in: `1,234` or `12,34` or `123,4`.

Comment: @Harmlezz I see, is there anything that allows formatting like #,#. Somewhat like DecimalFormat but for formatting input instead of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the data already formatted, but you can input the data as a String and format at.

Take a look at [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html?is-external=true) for formatting the number.

If you want to get each digit from a string, try getting the char from the String for each number, and then convert it to an `Integer` or an `int`.

Comment: Hey, if my question solved your probably con side clicking the checkmark under the arrows. It's gives us both some rep. And if it helped you or solved your problem, consider up voting it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex for the input and then change it into ints